# Ember serializers not working with Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember-data, active-model-serializers, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Updated to Rails 4.2 and now I cannot for the life of me get the ActiveModel::Serializer configuration to work correctly.

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.setup do |config|
  config.embed = :ids
  config.embed_in_root = true
end
```

Previously, this worked great with:

```
respond_with @thing
```

With 4.2 (and 0.9.2 AMS), you have to say:

```
respond_with @thing, root: true
```

explicitly. Anyone understand why the global `embed_in_root` config no longer works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same trouble...

It appears that active model serializers 0.9.2 is not compatible with Rails 4.2.

What I think may be happening in your case is when you call:

```
respond_with @thing, root: true
```

you are not using the Active Model Serializers gem at all. I tested this by adding a custom attribute in my active model serializer, like this:

```
class ThingSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :this_is_a_test

  def this_is_a_test
      "and it does not work"  
  end                       

end
```

The `this_is_a_test attribute` was not turning up in my JSON so I realized that the active model serializer was not in use.

I followed igagnidz and added this to my application controller:

```
def _render_with_renderer_json(json, options)
  serializer = build_json_serializer(json, options)

  if serializer
    super(serializer, options)
  else
    super(json, options)
  end

end
```

This is what finally got me through it: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/641